# Change Rubens Configurator Language after initializing

Tags: roomle

This is my first ever question on here so please excuse if I don't provide something that is needed for you to answer the question.

Anyways. I'm currently implementing a roomle configurator in a web page, that uses the weglot translator. However, the iframe isn't translated, because it is in another window element.

I'm trying to update the language in the configurator, when the language is selected in the dropdown. I found, that i can change the "locale" attribute when loading the configurator, but coulndn't find if there was a way to update the locale attribute down the line.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible to change the language of the Rubens configurator during runtime.

It would be possible to reload the configurator when your user changes the language in the dropdown and re-open the current configuration again.